# How do I put buttons in this column of my table?

Tags: php, html, bulma

I'm very much a beginner when it comes to PHP. I'm working on this project for my LAMP stack development class. This contacts page simply has a table that displays the contents of the contacts database. Right now, it's doing that just fine. However, the last column of the table is meant to be two buttons, one leading to the contact-update.php page, and one to the contact-delete.php page. This is the example our professor has given us:

[image]

However, I clearly don't understand redirect buttons in PHP well enough to get this working.

This is what my code looks like now. I'm just trying to put *something* in that last column of the table that displays those two buttons and brings you to an edit or delete page for whichever row you clicked the button of.

```
<?php
require 'config.php';

//php scripts will go here

//start new session
session_start();

//password protect this page
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}

$pdo = pdo_connect_mysql();

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `contacts`');
$stmt->execute();
$contacts = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
<?= template_header("Contacts") ?>
<?= template_nav() ?>

<!-- START PAGE CONTENT -->
<?php if ($userResponses) : ?>
    <p class="notification is-danger is-light">
        <?php echo implode('<br>', $userResponses);
        //var_dump ($_POST);
        ?>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
<h1 class="title">Contacts</h1>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Created</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<tr>" .
                "<td>" . $row["id"] . "</td>" .
                "<td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>" .
                "<td>" . $row["email"] . "</td>" .
                "<td>" . $row["phone"] . "</td>" .
                "<td>" . $row["title"] . "</td>" .
                "<td>" . $row["created"] . "</td>" .
                "<td>" . 
                    "<div class="buttons">
                        <a href="?id=<?= $contact['id']?>&confirm=yes" class="button is-success">Yes</a>
                        <a href="?id=<?= $contact['id']?>&confirm=no" class="button is-danger">No</a>
                    </div>" .
                "</td>" .
                "</tr>";
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!-- END PAGE CONTENT -->

<?= template_footer() ?>
```

Comment: The main problem seems to be you'll have php syntax errors because of putting unescaped double quotes in a double quoted string. That has nothing much to do with buttons. And you're also trying to put a php block inside another php block too. TBH the code would be better outside the echo anyway, in a static block with php blocks inside where you need them. It'll be easier to read too.